# Getting classcastexception for validation provider

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I am getting **class cast exception** when running a `jar` from a web application in `tomcat`.

The exception is :

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator cannot be cast to
>   javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider

I also tried to replace the hibernate validator jar to a different version , but it still gives the same error.

And when I remove the hibernate validator, I get no default provider error.

Comment: add jar to deployment assembly

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.jboss.org/message/651764#651764), if it helps?

Comment: The project I use is a maven project and this error occurs only when I run this code from tomcat, when I run it as a standalone code it works fine. Maven dependencies is already part of my eclipse web deployment assembly

Comment: I have the HibernateValidator added but looks like it cannot be cast to ValidationProvider, is there any other validator providers available which I can use?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem, the version of java and hibernate-validation I use are java11 and 7.0.1.Final. I use 6.2.0.Final version to avoid this problem.